# Paypal integration with java

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway

i want to know how to integrate paypal payment gateway with java. I need steps or sample code

Answer (score 5):

There's a complete Java SDK for the Classic API's as well as the new REST API's at http://paypal.github.io/

Additionally, "paypal payment gateway" doesn't exist.
PayPal is the company, and Website Payments Standard, Express Checkout, Website Payments Pro, Adaptive Payments, Express Checkout for Digital Goods, Payflow Link and Payflow Pro are their products.
Which product are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

check out the Integration Guide PDF to get you started. Also helpful is Name-Value Pair API (the easiest way to use their API's), the sample code, and the Sandbox User's Guide for testing.
[link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro)

Answer (score 0):

We can do paypal transaction with many way's .Here is the sample example of Express Checkout.

[Express Checkout Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/)